What is this biplane seen over Doncaster?
This plane passed over our house in Doncaster England and we’d like to know more about it please:


This one is decidedly easy to answer, a modern photo clearly showing the aircraft registration means you can search the UK database of registered aircraft.
G-EMNN is a FOCKE WULF FW44J built in 1936, and previously registered in Germany as D-EMNN.

You can also use the horizontal tail for identification. The FW-44 tail shape is like a fingerprint.

You might find this airplane's flight history on  https://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/g-emnn
